# how to format nested parentheses using .clang-format

Tags: c++, clang-format

I want to obtain the following code to create json object:

```
nlohmann::json obj = {
    {key1, "value 1"},
    {key2, 22}
};
```

Instead of

```
nlohmann::json obj = {{key1, "value 1"}, {key2, 22}};
```

Is it possible to do that using `.clang-format` settings?

Comment: AFAIK clang-format kind of depends on line length for this. Only starts to do the first if second no longer fits on a line.

Comment: Add a comma after ```{key2, 22}``` -> ```{key2, 22},```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar can be achieved with `AlignArrayOfStructures: Left`:

```cpp
nlohmann::json obj = {
    {key1, "value 1"},
    {key2, 22       }
};
```

You could also disable `clang-format` for those lines and format them manually:

```cpp
// clang-format off
nlohmann::json obj = {
    {key1, "value 1"},
    {key2, 22}
};
// clang-format on
```